# How to make containers start from the same position in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

Iam trying to create a figure like this using containers in flutter
[image: Iam trying to create an image like this using untainers]

I wrote the following code.

```
Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[       
          Container(width: 5, height: 10, color: Colors.green),
          Container(width: 5, height: 15, color: Colors.green),
          Container(width: 5, height: 20, color: Colors.green),
          Container(width: 5, height: 25, color: Colors.green),
          Container(width: 5, height: 30, color: Colors.green),
        ],
    ),
```

I get the follwing output.
[image]
How to I make all the containers to start from the same level.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end` to your `Row`

```dart
Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(width: 5, height: 10, color: Colors.green),
        Container(width: 5, height: 15, color: Colors.green),
        Container(width: 5, height: 20, color: Colors.green),
        Container(width: 5, height: 25, color: Colors.green),
        Container(width: 5, height: 30, color: Colors.green),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use this code

```
  Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(width: 5, height: 10, color: Colors.green),
          Container(width: 5, height: 15, color: Colors.green),
          Container(width: 5, height: 20, color: Colors.green),
          Container(width: 5, height: 25, color: Colors.green),
          Container(width: 5, height: 30, color: Colors.green),
        ],
      ),
```